# jdbc connections in clojure are garbage collected prematurely

Tags: jdbc, clojure, connection-leaks

I am using the `[com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng/pgjdbc-ng "0.7.1"]` library to connect to a postgres database.
The connection is saved inside an atom. 
I then arm multiple listeners like so:

```
(doto (.createStatement (connection f))
    (.execute (format "LISTEN %s;" event))
    (.closeOnCompletion)))
```

`f` in this case is a function called when the event triggers.
For some reason it does not take long until the connection seems to be garbage collected, which obviously makes the listeners non-functioning.

```
WARNING: Cleaning up leaked connection ( jdbc:pgsql://my-container/database )
```

This warning is followed by a stacktrace to where I opened the connection in the `arm-listeners` method.

I tried several things, like store the connection in a `let`, but none seemed to help with this specific issue.

The complete function to establish the connection and start the listener which I use are those: https://github.com/n2o/postgres-listener/blob/master/src/postgres_listener/core.clj

This is how I start the listeners:

```
(defn start-listeners
  "Start all important listeners."
  []
  (connect {:host (System/getenv "DB_HOST")
            :port (read-string (System/getenv "DB_PORT"))
            :database (System/getenv "DB_NAME")
            :user (System/getenv "DB_USER")
            :password (System/getenv "DB_PW")})
  (arm-listener handle-textversions "textversions_changes")
  (arm-listener handle-statements "statements_changes")
  (arm-listener handle-arguments "arguments_changes")
```

Comment: Could you give a more complete reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I added additional code and information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the connection in a `let` statement and than returning it, helps the JVM not to collect the reference.

So something like this would help:

```
(let [conn (connect <...>)
      a (arm-listener f name)]
   conn)
```

I'll keep the question open for a while, in case somebody has another answer.

Comment: This did not work for me. Looking for other answers.